# How do I take 2-second long exposures on the Google Pixel?

Tags: camera, google-pixel

[This post](http://research.googleblog.com/2017/04/experimental-nighttime-photography-with.html) on the Google blog says that the Pixel camera supports shutter speeds up to 2 seconds. But I'm unable to use shutter speeds longer than 0.7 seconds, no matter which app I use — Lightroom, Camera FV-5 and Open Camera.

Do I need to flash the Pixel with a custom build of Android in order to do this?